# Como Dividir un campo en varios - Oracle

Tags: oracle

Una duda, tengo una tabla con una columna que arroja información (Tipo identificador+Numero de empleado) de instructores.

Necesito separarlo en mi consulta para hacer un Join con las tablas correspondientes donde arroje su nombre completo, solo que no se cual sea la función para separarlo.

Ejemplo del campo.

`UsuarioActualización`

`INSTRUCTOR - A800000`

Yo necesito saber como dividir esa columna para que quede como la siguiente en 2 columnas:

`TipoUsuarioActualización` | `UsuarioActualización`

`INSTRUCTOR               | A800000`

Comment: Utiliza substring

Comment: Evita hacer la misma pregunta varias veces. Haz un seguimiento de tu pregunta original y completala si es necesario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es una alternativa que te podría servir...

```
SELECT SUBSTR(UsuarioActualizacion, 1, INSTR(UsuarioActualización, '-')-1) AS Tipo,
   SUBSTR(UsuarioActualizacion', INSTR(UsuarioActualización, '-')+1) AS Usuario
FROM Tabla
```

Asumiendo que siempre vienen separadas por '-'.

Para el Join con otra tabla, tendrías que hacerlo del siguiente modo:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(t.UsuarioActualizacion, 1, INSTR(t.UsuarioActualizacion, '-')-1) AS Tipo, SUBSTR(t.UsuarioActualizacion, INSTR(t.UsuarioActualizacion, '-')+1) AS Usuario, P.NombreCompleto
FROM Tabla t JOIN Personas P on TRIM(SUBSTR(UsuarioActualizacion, INSTR(UsuarioActualizacion, '-')+1))=P.Usuario
```

Aplicando el TRIM como sugiere @DamianAlva

Comment: Gracias! una duda, si funciona , quise partir estas columnas debido a que el campo de "Usuario" necesito hacer un JOIN con la tabla de Personas para poder traerme su "Nombre completo", es esto posible?  ya que no estaría referenciando a una tabla si no a una columna. Es decir poder hacer un Join con Personas donde el idPersona sea el mismo de la columna "Usuario".

Comment: Ahora no tengo como probarlo, pero algo como lo siguiente te puede funcionar:
SELECT SUBSTR(t.UsuarioActualizacion, 1, INSTR(t.UsuarioActualización, '-')-1) AS Tipo,
   SUBSTR(t.UsuarioActualizacion', INSTR(t.UsuarioActualización, '-')+1) AS Usuario, P.NombreCompleto
FROM Tabla t JOIN Personas P on TRIM(SUBSTR(&UsuarioActualizacion, INSTR(&UsuarioActualizacion, '-')+1))=P.Usuario

Lo pongo en la respuesta actualizada para mejor visualización...

Comment: Mil gracias Me funcionó ;)

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que los datos siempre vienen con el mismo formato (guión entre los dos campos) se puede hacer los siguiente:

```
SELECT
  'INSTRUCTOR - A800000' AS cadena,
  TRIM(SUBSTRING(cadena, 1, CHARINDEX('-', cadena) - 1)) AS TipoUsuarioActualizacion,
  TRIM(SUBSTRING(cadena, CHARINDEX('-', cadena) + 1)) AS UsuarioActualizacion;
```

En caso de que `SUBSTRING` no funcione en `Oracle`, probar con [SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm)

Qué es lo que se hace:

1. Con `CHARINDEX` se obtiene la posición del caracter separador (el guión).
2. con `SUBSTRING` se obtiene una subcadena de la original. El primer parametro es la cadena original, el segundo el indice desde donde se quiere extraer y el tercero la cantidad de caracteres a extraer. en caso de omitirse el último, se extrae hasta el final de la cadena.
3. Con `TRIM` se eliminan los espacios en blanco sobrantes luego de haber extraído los datos.

Este proceso puede demorar para muchos registros debido a que se deben aplicar funciones.